# Sass mixin or function to return mixins

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I want to write functions/mixins which return a mixin. For example I have this mixin:

```css
@mixin generate-offsets-from-map($class-slug,$type,$from, $to, $step) {
    $i: $from;
    @while $i <= $to {
        @if ($type == "vertical") {
            .#{$class-slug}-#{$type}-#{$i}, @mixin {$class-slug}-#{$type}-#{$i} { 
                padding: {
                    top: $i * 1px;
                    bottom: $i * 1px;
                }
            }
        
        } @else if ($type == "horizontal") {
            .#{$class-slug}-#{$type}-#{$i}, %#{$class-slug}-#{$type}-#{$i} {
                padding: {
                    left: $i * 1px;
                    right: $i * 1px;
                }
            }
        }
        
        $i: $i + $step;
    }
}
@include generate-offsets-from-map(offset,vertical,10,100,1);
```

I generate classes offset-vertical/horizintal-1/100 but I want generate @mixin offset-vertical/horizintal-1/100.

Answer (score 0):

Mixins may not be defined within control directives or other mixins.

Comment: its only example I need find solution how to generate mixins

Comment: Ok. But there is no way to generate mixins :(

Can you explain why do you need to generate mixins?

Comment: I want to include mixins in "@media", i cant ude "@extend" in MQ.
So i have idea if i can generate mixins with properties like placeholders I can include it in MQ.

Comment: e.x: "@media" offset-10 {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
"@media" all and (max-width: 768px) {
     a {
        "@include" offset-10 
  }
}

Comment: Ok, I understand you.

Comment: Check it https://www.sitepoint.com/cross-media-query-extend-sass/ 
http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9638030